# Getting TypeError: Network request failed while POSTing to my node server from Physical Device

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, post, android-manifest

**What I Want:**

- POST some credentials to my node server on Signup and save the user in MongoDB

**What's Wrong:**

- TypeError: Network request failed on POST Request from React Native

**What I have Done**:

- Change Local Host to my machine's IP
- Add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in Android Manifest
- Used IP generated by ngork
- Checked my server code using POSTMAN, its working fine!

**React Native CODE:**

*POST Request:*

```
fetch('http://MY_MACHINE_IPv4:3001/signup', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    fullName: fullName,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    password: pass,
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

*Node's Code:*

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    const { fullName, email, phone, password } = req.body
  console.log("The Email in request is ", email)
  console.log("The Password in request is ", password)
  try {
    const user = new User({ fullName, email, phone, password })
    console.log("USER BEING SAVED")
    await user.save()
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, jwtKey)
    res.send({ token: token })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(422).send(err.message)
  }
})
```

*Error:*

WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed
TypeError: Network request failed
at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:25389:33)
at apply (native)
at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29526:26)
at _callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29446:17)
at callTimers (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29647:19)
at apply (native)
at __callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:6319:36)
at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:6043:31)
at __guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:6270:15)
at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.healthapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:6042:21)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an android emulator,Android emulator always sent charset: utf-8 on the header. so you need to changed the nginx setting to allow that additional header

Comment: I have written in the title that I am using a Physical Device.